# Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 does not show any project's files and folder?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Why my Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 community version is not showing any files and folders?

Please Help me to get the project's files and folders.

Comment: Did you load a project? Probably not.

Comment: I just create a project asp.net.cor web-api. but does not showing any files and folders such a programe.cs

Comment: Ok, I see in the Screenshot that you have actually "WebApplication3" open. No idea why it is like this. Did you try to open it again (File->Open->Project)? Or just close VS and open again?

Comment: No this is the first time i created a project...

Comment: also i cannot run the application

Comment: Well, please try the things I mentioned in my comment above.

Comment: I did it, but It is not working.

Comment: Sorry, no idea what else could be wrong.

Comment: Find a folder on the local disk, and use `dotnet new webapi` to create a brand new project. Then open its project file in VS 2022 and see what happens.

Answer (score 4):

OK, I fixed this, at least on my PC...turns out that my path variable had the X86 version above the 64 version.

If you go to a command line and type dotnet --list-sdks and it returns nothing, make sure you have SDKS installed by checking directory C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdks and seeing if you have any subdirectories.

If you do....its most likely your environmental variable Path statement for the system has the C:\Program Files(x86)\dotnet above the c:\Program Files\dotnet statement.  This fixed it for me!

Comment: thank you so much @jeff for your contribution